# how to use query parameters with limit and interval in spring data jpa with Query annotation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a native query to be used in @Query annotation in spring. The problem is that I cannot pass parameters for non standard clauses like LIMIT AND INTERVAL.

1) Is it possible to do pass the parameters for LIMIT in the annotation.
2) What is the programmatic equivalent in JPA. Does it have any query interface which can be used ?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM scheduler sch where timestamp < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '1 seconds') FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT 5",nativeQuery = true)
```

Also, the limit and interval clause are not to be changed for every query but should be set when the jvm starts up.

Comment: You can use `Pageable` as parameter in your method signature.

Comment: Can you add your query method signature ?

Answer (score 0):

Two Step 
1. Use `Pageable pageable` as a parameter in your method signature
2. Create object of `PageRequest` and call repository method by passing the pageRequest Object.

```
PageRequest pageRequest=new PageRequest(0,5); // 0 is page (used to calculate offset) and 5 is size (limit).
```

Pass the `pageRequest` object to the method.

For INTERVAL, if you are using seconds, use like below.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM scheduler sch where timestamp < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + ((interval '1 seconds') * :seconds)) FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED",nativeQuery = true)
```

Pass `:seconds` as another parameter.

For the parameters to be constant, you can create a `public static final` variable.

Comment: what about interval ??

Comment: Oh, I missed that part.

Comment: is this tested ?

Comment: That is the syntax. Try it out!